# Can we use an API to manage this data in an administration?

Tags: php, api, frontend, back

Hello I am doing this subject to have more details concerning a web application that I am developing.

I am currently using react for the front, for the back-end I use a php poo api that I have developed.

I would like to know if I can still use the front in administration and continue to use my API to manage my data whether it is read write or update?

Is it a good practice to use an API to be able to manage my data in an administration?

Exemple Api back end :

```
<?php

// Headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include('../../config/Database.php');
include('../../models/post.php');

// DB CONNECT

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->connect();

    $post = new Post($db);
    $stmt = $post->read();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $arrayPost = [];
        $arrayPost['post'] = [];

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            extract($row);
            $posts= [
                'id' => $id,
                'title' => $title,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'categorie_id' => $categorie_id,
                'body' => utf8_decode($body),
                'author' => $author,
                'resolved' => $resolved
            ];

            $arrayPost['post'][] = $posts;
        }

        http_response_code(200);
        echo json_encode($arrayPost);
    }

}else {
    http_response_code(405);
    echo json_encode(["message" => "La méthode n'est pas autorisée"]);
}
```

example recovery of my API :

```
await axios.get(urlPost).then(res => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message)
  })
```

If I create an administration on my front, can I continue to use my API to be able to edit a post or user or even delete ?
I would like to know if it is a good practice

Comment: What is “data in an administration”? Maybe you need to include an example, I’m not sure what you’re trying to achieve here.

Comment: @prieber i edit my post